# Android Bluetooth sample, device list activity causes app crash when no device is picked

Tags: bluetooth

If I select a device to connect from the device list activity, the code runs fine.
However, if I choose not to connect and press back button or click any other screen but not the device list activity to dismiss the pop up list activity, my app would crash.

the following is the error that I got

10-29 17:02:02.235: E/AndroidRuntime(12852): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=0, data=null} to activity {com.ensil.vastusyscontrolunit/com.ensil.vastusyscontrolunit.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Oh I think I got it.  It's because the data intent is null

Answer (score 1):

You can try bluetoothAdapter.stopDiscovery() method inside your onPause() method of the listActivity...It will help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button then response is send from DevicelistActivity class to BluetoothChat class through intent.If no any device is selected then it sends null through intent.That cause null pointer exception at run time.